# How to resolve SQL timeout error in a window service application?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, service

I have a web app which has been added as a reference to my window service app. The service will call a method in the web app which then will invoke the database to run a stored procedure.

I received an exception while calling one of my stored procedure. The stored procedure will run for approximately 45 seconds.

This is the error I get:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout
> Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the
> operation or the server is not responding. --->
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation
> timed out

I have tried to increase the service app timeout by appending `;Connection Timeout=3600` to the service app conn string in `web.config` but the exception still occurred after around 30 seconds of running.

Your help to resolve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: set it in `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` Property

Comment: But you should really take a look why that query why it takes more than 30 secs

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @Squirrel comment:

Your error message shows a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`. So the timeout is on SQL Server side.

So if you want to increase the timeout, it must be done on the SQL Server side.

In the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace you seem to use, the `SqlCommand` class that you probably use to call your stored procedure has a property `CommandTimeout` that let you set the timeout value.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

> **CommandTimeout**
>
> Gets or sets the wait time (in seconds) before
> terminating the attempt to execute a command and generating an error.